# Normalize a vector where the dot product equals 1 in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I already know, and understand how I can normalize an array in Python, but I am trying to create a random array.  I want the dot product of the array (when I dot it with itself) to equal a value of one.  I have been looking for a way to do this for over twelve hours now, and can not find a way.  Any help or ideas would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: One second I will get the code if you would like.

Comment: that would be good, SO is not a code writing service and people look for askers that have made some effort beforehand and ideally have something to show for it

Comment: Just to be clear on what your asking, you want to generate a pseudorandom vector of which the dot product (with itself) is 1?

Comment: Well I was trying to get python up so I could get the code, but then I got the notification that he answered.  I will make sure to include my work for now on.  To be technical yes I did mean generating a pseudorandom vector of which the dot product is 1.

Comment: _"magnitude is 1"_ would be a better way to phrase that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import numpy as  np
x=np.random.randn(5)
x=x/np.linalg.norm(x)
```

Then `np.dot(x,x)` is 1.0